# What is the appropriate test for significance when comparing a subset of the population to the whole?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, proportion

I am looking for discrepancies in performance evaluation data. For example, let's say I have a population that has 240,000 men and 86,000 women. So 326,000 individuals and 73.6% male/26.4% female. Then I look at the portion that received the highest rating on the evaluation and find that there are 197,395 individuals and they break down 74.4% male and 25.6% female. So it's been put to me that men are over-represented and women under-represented in this evaluation category.

What is the appropriate test to say whether those differences in percentages are significant? If I were to perform a two proportion Z-test would I not need to back the top evaluation category individuals out of the rest of the population?

Comment: You have only *one* independent random proportion: 74.4% male.  What is the chance that a random sample (without replacement) of 197,395 individuals from the population would be at least this much "enriched" in males?  You can just calculate that directly and reason accordingly.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how would I calculate that directly?

Comment: You can use [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) to calculate the probability of drawing 146,862 or more males when you draw 197,395 people from a population where the Pr(Male) = 0.736.

Comment: Given the large sample sizes, even with the normal approximation to the binomial that's not really feasible is it?

Comment: I had no trouble doing this on my laptop without approximation. The binomial CDF is just a sum, so you need to calculate the probability of drawing 146,861 or fewer males, and then subtract that from 1. There are also online and functions in statistics packages that can take the three numbers as arguments and return the answer.

Comment: Would a chi-square goodness of fit be apt in this case?

Comment: @Dmitri This one requires the hypergeometric distribution (or else a good approximation to it, such as the Normal).  Because the sample is such a large proportion of the population, the Binomial calculation will be wrong.

Comment: Not sure where sampling without replacement comes in. Suppose we have 300 men, 300 women of which 160 & 130, resp. get top scores. In R: `mw = c(300, 300);  top = c(160, 130);  bot=mw-top;`
`TBL = rbind(top, bot);` In R, `prop.test` is `chisq.test` with different syntax: `chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)$p.val` returns $0.01425187$ as does
`prop.test(top, mw, cor=F)$p.val`. Of course, if you want to use Fisher's exact test. then the hypergeometric dist'n is used: `fisher.test(TBL)$p.val` returns $0.01775527.$

Comment: @BruceET Following this procedure with the data in the OP then gives a p-value on the order of 5.32e-36...so just to be sure I'm interpreting that correctly that says there's a vanishingly small probability that the difference in proportions is due to random variation as opposed to an actual difference, correct?

Comment: Yes, in statistical language, there is a highly significant difference. (With so much data, it is not unusual to find a significant difference.) However, in a practical sense the difference between proportions 0.612 and 0.588 might not be of importance. Both proportions are close to 60%.

Comment: I suspected that with such large sample sizes it wouldn't take much to be "significant" but now that I have a handle on the process I can start to look at other slices of the data (e.g. men vs women amongst 35-45 year-olds in a certain occupational series at a specific location) in a consistent manner...if you'd like to submit your comment as an answer I'd happily accept it

Comment: jerH wrote: "now that I have a handle on the process I can start to look at other slices of the data". If you compare many subgroups ("strata"), you might run in the multiple testing problem shown in this cartoon: https://xkcd.com/882/ Moreover, when reporting your results, you should not drop "statistically" from "statistically significant", because, as @bruceet pointed out, with such a large sample size, even minimal (and thus practically insignifcant) differences become "statistically significant". A difference of only 0.8 precent might not justify much ado...

Answer (score 3):

Sampling without replacement can be modelled using the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). Using the notation from the Wikipedia article, denote $N$ the population size (326,000), $K$ the number of males in the population (240,000), $n$ the number of draws (197,395) and $k$ the number of observed males in the sample (146,862).

Using the upper tail of the CDF of the hypergeometric distribution we can directly answer the question

> Assuming random sampling without replacement from the population
> containing 240,000 men, what's the probability that we end up with
> 146,862 or more men in a sample of size 197,395?

The answer is found using software. Here, I'm using `R` (the parametrization is a bit different compared to the Wikipedia article):

```R
m <- 240000 # Number of men in the population
n <- 86000  # Number of women in the population
k <- 197395 # Sample size
x <- 146862 # Number of men in the sample

# Calculate the upper tail probabiltiy of the hypergeometric distribution
phyper(x - 1, m, n, k, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 3.592856e-36
```

The probability is essentially zero.

A normal approximation also works well here and simplifies the calculations considerably. The mean of the hypergeometric distribution is $n\frac{K}{N}=145321.5$ and the variance is $n{K\over N}{(N-K)\over N}{N-n\over N-1} = 15123.5$. The corresponding probability based on the normal approximation is (again in `R`):

```R
p <- m/(m + n)
mu_approx <- k*p
sd_approx <- sqrt(k*p*(1 - p)*(m + n - k)/(m + n - 1))

# Calculate the upper tail probabiltiy of the hypergeometric distribution
pnorm(trueval - 1, mean = mu_approx, sd = sd_approx, lower.tail = FALSE)
2.947386e-36
```

A simple simulation confirms the above considerations:

```R
# The population
pop <- rep(0:1, times = c(86000, 240000))
# Reproducibility
set.seed(142857)
# Simulation
res <- replicate(1e4, {
  sum(sample(pop, size = 197395, replace = FALSE))
})
# Histogram of the number of males (not shown)
hist(res, breaks = 100)
# Mean and standard deviation
mean(res)
[1] 145322.1
sd(res)
[1] 123.8935
```